# Is there a simple BASIC program that demonstrates SID6581 distortion?

Tags: commodore-64, audio

Many songs use a SID6581 design "flaw", distortion, as an effect.  I tried experimenting with the filter and resonance registers, but was unable to reproduce the sound.  What conditions are necessary for the distortion to occur and is the distortion easily demonstrable in a simple BASIC program?

Comment: Ah, the [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) strikes again.

Comment: I'm a bit disappointed that the Related Questions didn't list [this question](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/667). The answer there indicates that the distortion varies from chip to chip, so the effects are likely quite variable.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by distortion. The best known flaw of the 6581 was that when changing volume levels (0-15) a click proportional to the delta was emitted - this was exploited to play 4-bit samples. Is this what you are referring to?